# Can TOR be downloaded on IOS 10.3?

Tags: ios

- Have a IPAD and trying to download TOR, comes up in my Dropbox. Not allowing me to "view the file". Is there some other way to do this on ipad and iphone??*

Answer (score 0):

Currently the best browser is https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/onion-browser-secure-anonymous-web-with-tor/id519296448?mt=8
it is open source, tor project is still working on a official version. That is the best option right now.